# Modified react-datepicker not showing value

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react v.15. Using the react-datepicker library is giving issues when using the default code. I've successfully modified the codes but whenever I click on the selected date, it's not showing any date at all. Here's what my code looks like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
let DatePicker = require('react-datepicker');
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

export default class DtePicker extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date(),
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(date) {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DatePicker
                    dateFormat='yyyy/MM/dd'
                    selected={this.state.startDate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Am I missing a code perhaps in my handleChange function? Also, it's a typescript file, using ASP.Net framework.
```

Comment: What specific version of react are you using. Also, what specific version of `react-datepicker` are you using? Here is the [compatibilty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker#compatibility) for `react-datepicker I'm unable to get your code to run in codesandbox (tried react v15.0.0 - 15.5.0) and (react-datepicker v2.9.3 and older).

Comment: @DrewReese react is 15.4.1, and the compatible react-datepicker version is 0.40.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After specifying the versions I was seeing a "date.clone is not a function" error, so I suspected there was an issue with `moment`.

`react-datepicker` v0.40.0 uses moment under the hood

[**issue 1120**: DatePicker breaks with "date.clone is not a function" when "selected" date is passed down as a prop](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1120)

Selected date must be a `moment` object, so we save each date object as a `moment` date object.

```
class DtePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // Don't forget to pass props to super constructor!
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment(new Date())
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: moment(date)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          dateFormat="YYYY/MM/dd" // Also corrected date format
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit react-datepicker]

- moment v2.24.0
- react v15.4.1
- react-datepicker v0.40.0
- react-dom v15.4.1

Comment: Finally made progress now. Dropdown's working fine now but the language seems to hinder the page from loading whenever I import registerlocale.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it's working properly

```
import React from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

    class DtePicker extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          startDate: new Date()
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(date) {
        this.setState({
          startDate: date
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <DatePicker
              dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
              selected={this.state.startDate}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Check this live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-obbcg)

Comment: As I've said, I'm using an older react. So I have to modify my codes by not using the default codes. So that would  not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to update to a new version of React.